# BizTalk orchestration inner exception

Tags: xml, biztalk, biztalk-2013

While debugging an orchestration I received an unhandled exception when calling another orchestration.

I'm passing in 2 string parameters and an XML message but I'm guessing it has something to do with the mark-up around the message. I have not been able to find much specific to BizTalk around this error so any suggestions are welcome

> Inner exception: To be XML serializable, types which inherit from IEnumerable must have an implementation of Add(System.Object) at all levels of their inheritance hierarchy.

Comment: Passing how? To what?  Can you give us some more details.  A reproducible code sample would be ideal.

Comment: At the point of failure there is no code as such, it's a call orchestration shape - the orchestration accepts in 2 string parameters and a message parameter but fails before it gets to do anything, like it doesn't like the incoming message.  I'm thinking of shifting the called orchs to a different app anyway to keep in line with our ESB design, so with the appropriate headers in the message it should work that way.